# Floating elements filling up the top gaps of a container?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Is it possible to have HTML elements with the same width (100px) and different heights filling up all the gaps in the top end of a container with a fixed width (300px)?

What I have got so far. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Adsgn/vXyxV/)

As you can see, the 4th, 5th and 6th block do not fill up the gaps above. Is that possible somehow without the need of Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with pure CSS using the html layout you're using. There's a plugin called Masonry that is popular fior this kind of layout: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: What about using a differtent HTML layout?

Comment: @Apex you can do it using tables, but tables shouldn't be used for designing your layout

Comment: You could simply have columns with your different elements dropping in to the columns but that's not so easy to implement dynamically/programmatically. If it's just a static layout you have then it may work fine.